# Swift : Scan QR from photos gallery using AVFoundation framework

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I want to scan QR code fetched from photos gallery. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317071/scan-qrcode-and-barcode-from-camera-and-image-which-picked-from-image-library-in) has something similar but didn’t helped much.
I’ve implemented scan QR functionality using camera successfully. Below is code for this :

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
    {
        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
//            lblMesage.text = QRCaptureFailedMessage
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        // Here we use filter method to check if the type of metadataObj is supported
        // Instead of hardcoding the AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, we check if the type
        // can be found in the array of supported bar codes.
        if supportedBarCodes.contains(metadataObj!.type) {
            //        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj!.stringValue != nil {

                . . .
            }
        }
   }


func scanQRFromGallery(qrcodeImg : UIImage) {

        let detector:CIDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])!
        let ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(image:qrcodeImg)!
        var qrCodeLink=""

        let features=detector.features(in: ciImage)

        for feature in features as! [CIQRCodeFeature] {
            qrCodeLink += feature.messageString!
        }

        if qrCodeLink=="" {
            print("qrCodeLink is empty")
        }
        else{
            print("message: \(qrCodeLink)")
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40254225/3548469

Comment: let me know if it helps

Comment: @Dev_Tandel it works as on today. slightly modified code posted there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to scan the code from the gallery photo. For additional information about the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class QRScanner: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard
            let qrcodeImg = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as? UIImage,
            let detector: CIDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]),
            let ciImage: CIImage = CIImage(image:qrcodeImg),
            let features = detector.features(in: ciImage) as? [CIQRCodeFeature]
        else {
            print("Something went wrong")
            return
        }
        var qrCodeLink = ""
        features.forEach { feature in
            if let messageString = feature.messageString {
                qrCodeLink += messageString
            }
        }
        if qrCodeLink.isEmpty {
            print("qrCodeLink is empty!")
        } else {
            print("message: \(qrCodeLink)")
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

You can read this article:
[Scan QR Code From Gallery Swift](https://mobikul.com/scan-qr-code-from-gallery-swift/)